# How can I change the content of an iframe with form post

Tags: php, html, iframe

Ok so I have this code :

```
<body>
    <div id="top_bar">
        <a target="content_frame" href="main/index.php"> Home | </a>
        <a target="content_frame" href="faq/index.html"> FAQ | </a>
        <a target="content_frame" href="contact/index.html"> Contact </a>
        <div id="search">
            <form method="POST" action="/php/search.php">
                Search: <input type="text" name="search_box">
                <input id="search_button" type="submit" value="Search">
            <form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <iframe name="content_frame" src="main/index.php"></iframe>
</body>
```

And the webpage looks something like this:
[image: My webpage]

How do I make it so when someone writes something in the search_box and presses ENTER it doesn't change the whole page but it acts on the iframe instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the target attribute of the form should do the job :)

```
<form method="POST" action="/php/search.php" target="content_frame">
    Search: <input type="text" name="search_box">
    <input id="search_button" type="submit" value="Search">
<form>
```